# Show / Hide HTML based on Authentication

Tags: angular, angular7

On an Angular 7 application I have a few components where content must be visible / hidden depending on if the user is authenticated or not or if it has a specific claim or not ...

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

I have an AuthService as follows:

```
export class AuthService {

  hasClaim(claim: Claim) : boolean { }

  isSignedIn(): boolean { }

  // Other methods

}
```

What would be the best way to show / hide parts of a view's HTML based on authentication?

Comment: in the html element do an `*ngIf` that hits a method that checks your isSignedIn method of the service? e.g. `<div *ngIf="checkIsSignedIn()"></div>`?

Comment: You can add authentication check in ngOnInit()

Comment: Personally I like to hide all of this type of logic behind a route guard, so that I know everything after passing this will have access to the properties you want. From experience it makes it more maintainable as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an instance of the service in the component which use that view, and simply use  `<div *ngIf="yourcomponent.serviceInstance.isSignedIn()"></div>`. If Im not wrong, though previous approach is also good.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think @Jaime_c7 approach will work because the service is set as private in the constructor and calling from outside the component.ts file will not work that is why I set it up the way in my original comment.

In your html:

```
<div *ngIf="checkIsSignedIn()">Whatever you are showing or hiding</div>
```

component.ts:

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
checkIsSignedIn() {
    this.authService.isSignedIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add authentication check in `ngOnInit()` for the components you want to make visible or hide.
Like this:

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  visible: boolean = true;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.visible = this.authService.isSignedIn();
  }

}
```

And add `*ngIf = "visible"` in your top parent div of your template.

Answer (score 0):

We have had user roles, and I have liked the following **[approach](https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-structural-directives-in-angular-bfe4d8c44fb1)** by using a directive. You can modify the directive as you want. Here's an updated version of that piece of role based code:

```ts
@Directive({selector: '[appIfRole]'})
export class IfRoleDirective {
  user$ : Subscription;
  @Input("appIfRole") roleName : string;

  constructor( private templateRef : TemplateRef<any>,
               private viewContainer : ViewContainerRef,
               private authService : AuthService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     // returns current user
    this.user$ = this.authService.user.pipe(
      tap(() => this.viewContainer.clear()),
      filter(user => user.role === this.roleName)
    )
    .subscribe(() => this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.user$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Then this is easily usable like:

```html
<div *appIfRole="'admin'">
  Only for Admin
</div>
```

So there is the basic idea and you can modify the directive to your needs.